# How to search two tables for the given input in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

In my application, there are `article` and `news` tables. I know I can search for matching title in news table or article, 
just by doing something like:

```
$query =  $request['search'];

$searchResult= DB::table('article')->where('title', 'LIKE', '%$query%')
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

or

```
$searchResult= DB::table('news')->where('title', 'LIKE', '%$query%')
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

but what I want to do is to search both of them and return some information about them alongside what the reuslt type is, in terms of news and article. And than orther them by `created_at` as if they were in the same table.

> Laravel 5.4

Comment: Is this a good idea? Both table with have different columns, so there is no possibility to search in both tables in one query. Why not run two queries and merge the output in PHP?

Comment: Yeah that is excactly right. My only issue is that I don't know how to merge them while also knowing their type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that if getting 10 news and 10 articles per page is what you want. But in this case, you'll need to [manually create paginator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator).

Load the data:

```
$articles = DB::table('article')
    ->where('title', 'like', '%$query%')
    ->latest()
    ->skip(0) 
    ->take(10)
    ->get();

$news = DB::table('news')
    ->where('title', 'like', '%$query%')
    ->latest()
    ->skip(0) 
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

Then merge the results:

```
$merged = $articles->merge($news);
```

Then order by date if you need to:

```
$merged = $merge->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

Comment: Hah I see, Let me try that real quick. But can't I add ->pagenate(10); to it? I feel like I can. I will try and give feedback

Comment: @Nikonah you can merge paginator instances, but I'm not sure if pagination will work as expected.

Comment: BTW how do you know if the result is news or article in this case?

Comment: I made it work somehow, but the result is messy I don't know which row comes from wich table, do you have any idea how I can go around this?

Comment: @Nikonah it depends on what exactly do you want to get and on how are you merging these collections. You could iterate over both collections or use `map()` to transform these collections. If you use my code, it will work without any additional data transformations. But in this case, you'll need to create a paginator manually.

Comment: I used your code made almost no change, but I can't tell if the row I have in view is a `news` or `article`

Comment: @Nikonah you can always check the type of each object.

Comment: I see, I changed the code like `->where('title', 'like', $query)` and when I try to search a single word in title it doesn't work, It wants the entire title

Comment: @Nikonah you should add `%` to the string when you use `like`.

Comment: I have seen that before, but when I write it as  `'%$query%'` it doesnt work at all

Comment: @Nikonah try `'%' . $query . '%'` or `'%{$query}%`

Comment: Thanks, I tried `'%' . $query . '%'` and it worked. appreciate your help :)